# Reading DCD files using Python without using third party packages?

Tags: python, fortran

I am trying to read a Nanoscale Molecular Dynamics (NAMD), Dihedral Coordinates (DCD) file using Python. Following the code given at [here](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/namd/wiki/index.cgi?ReadingDCDinFortran) to read DCD files using Fortran, I have written the following code snippet to read the header section of the DCD file.

```py
import struct
import typing


class Trajectory:
    def __init__(self, psfname: str, dcdfile: str) -> None:
        self.psfName = psfname
        self.dcdFile = dcdfile
        self.nAtoms = 0
        self.nFrames = 0
        self.readDCD()

    def readDCD(self) -> None:
        with open(self.dcdFile, "rb") as dcd:
            header = dcd.read(92)
            test = struct.unpack("4s", header[0:4])[0]
            print(header)


trajectory = Trajectory(
    "/home/ssm_grp/project2/jpcb.paper/stripped/additive/adenine/stripped.ade.psf",
    "/home/ssm_grp/project2/jpcb.paper/stripped/additive/adenine/stripped.ade.full.add.dcd",
)
```

The Fotran code gave the value `'CORD'` which is expected, while the python code gave `b'T\x00\x00\x00'`

Edit: I figured that this bitstring `b'T\x00\x00\x00'` corresponds to the value 84, indicating that the DCD file is in little-endian format. Now I am confused as to why is that four bits not read in Fortran. Any reference on why this is happening, or how to read DCD files in python would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you not want to use third party packages? MDAnalysis is quite good, and cross-platform and it can work with DCD files.

Comment: @SRMaiti, I have been working with MDAnalysis codes for my analysis scripts. This is just a side project for me.

Comment: @HemanthHaridas could you please add the input DCD file? And what is the correct output you expect ? Also please add the full forms of the words NAMD and DCD

Comment: You can check the source code for chemfiles: https://github.com/chemfiles/chemfiles/blob/master/src/formats/DCD.cpp, they implement DCD reader in C++, you maybe able to translate that into python. (Fortran is much less understandable than C++ imo)

Comment: @VandanRevanur, I would not be able to share the DCD file because it is from an unpublished work. NAMD stands for Nanoscale Molecular Dynamics and DCD stands for Dihedral Coordinates

Comment: @HemanthHaridas Could you please clarify what the number 92 means in `dcd.read(92)`? Also what is `struct.unpack("4s", header[0:4])[0]` supposed to do?

Comment: @HemanthHaridas could you put in some dummy values in the DCD file and share it?

Comment: It reads the first 92 bytes of data from the binary file. struct.unpack unpacks the first four bytes as a string.

Comment: I'll remind everyone that if you need more space, there's a Python chat room on MMSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some digging around, I found this [webpage](https://github.com/priimak/scala-data/blob/master/NAMD-DCD-File-Format.md) which gave some hints to the specific padding required to read the various data from the DCD header. Even though the data given in the above mentioned webpage was not completely correct, I could just print out the specific bits to figure out the rest. Given below is a working code that can read the header section of the DCD file.

````py
import struct
import typing
import numpy 
import os

class Trajectory:
    def __init__(self, psf: str, dcd: str) -> None:
        self.psf = psf
        self.dcd = dcd
        self.__readDCD__()

    def __readDCD__(self):
        with open(self.dcd, "rb") as DCDReader:
            header = DCDReader.read(272)
            endian = struct.unpack("i", header[0:4])[0]                 # Must be equal to 84
            cordst = struct.unpack("4s", header[4:8])[0]                # CORD
            
            # Trajectory information
            nframe = struct.unpack("i", header[8:12])[0]                # Number of frames
            iframe = struct.unpack("i", header[12:16])[0]               # First frame in DCD file
            stride = struct.unpack("i", header[16:20])[0]               # Stride between two consecutive frames
            lframe = struct.unpack("i", header[20:24])[0]               # Last frame in DCD file
            nframe = int((lframe - iframe) / stride)

            # List of five zeros => Does not do anything
            fzero1 = struct.unpack("i", header[24:28])[0]
            fzero2 = struct.unpack("i", header[28:32])[0]
            fzero3 = struct.unpack("i", header[32:36])[0]
            fzero4 = struct.unpack("i", header[36:40])[0]
            fzero5 = struct.unpack("i", header[40:44])[0]

            timest = struct.unpack("f", header[44:48])[0]               # Timestep
            testst = struct.unpack("i", header[48:52])[0]               # 

            nzero1 = struct.unpack("i", header[52:56])[0]
            nzero2 = struct.unpack("i", header[56:60])[0]
            nzero3 = struct.unpack("i", header[60:64])[0]
            nzero4 = struct.unpack("i", header[64:68])[0]
            nzero5 = struct.unpack("i", header[68:72])[0]
            nzero6 = struct.unpack("i", header[72:76])[0]
            nzero7 = struct.unpack("i", header[76:80])[0]
            nzero8 = struct.unpack("i", header[80:84])[0]
            nzero9 = struct.unpack("i", header[84:88])[0]
           
            ntitle = struct.unpack("i", header[96:100])[0]              # number of title strings
            tsizes = 100 + ntitle*80                                    # size of title strings            
            tbsize = struct.unpack("i", header[tsizes:tsizes+4])[0]     # size of title block
            constv = struct.unpack("i", header[tsizes+4:tsizes+8])[0]   # value 4
            natoms = struct.unpack("i", header[tsizes+8:tsizes+12])[0]  # Number of atoms
            # Read the first 272 bytes of data and parse the header information

            # Just a hack to find the number of remaining bytes
            DCDReader.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
            remainingSize   = DCDReader.tell() - 272
            DCDReader.seek(272, 0)
            
            firstframe  = DCDReader.read(60)
            testvl  = struct.unpack("i", firstframe[4:8])[0]    # size of pbc length
            pbcvecx = struct.unpack("d", firstframe[8:16])[0]   # PBC length in x
            pbcvecy = struct.unpack("d", firstframe[24:32])[0] # PBC length in y
            pbcvecz = struct.unpack("d", firstframe[48:56])[0] # PBC length in z
            gamma   = struct.unpack("d", firstframe[16:24])[0]  # gamma
            beta    = struct.unpack("d", firstframe[40:48])[0]  # beta
            alpha   = struct.unpack("d", firstframe[32:40])[0]  # alpha
            print(testvl, pbcvecx, pbcvecy, pbcvecz, gamma, beta, alpha)
#            print(consta, testvl, pbcvecx, pbcvecy, pbcvecz, numpy.arccos(alpha)*180/numpy.pi, numpy.arccos(beta)*180/numpy.pi, numpy.arccos(gamma)*180/numpy.pi)
```
````